# 'HelpSelect' has no attribute to 'commands'

Tags: python, nextcord

I am getting the following error: 'HelpSelect' has no attribute to 'commands' whenever someone choses an option in the dropdown.

Here is my code:

```
class HelpSelect(nextcord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options = [
            nextcord.SelectOption(label= 'Fun', description= 'Fun commands', emoji= '<:blanket:915928436223143956>'),
            nextcord.SelectOption(label= 'Economy', description= 'Economy commands', emoji= ''),
            nextcord.SelectOption(label= 'Utility', description= 'Utility commands', emoji= '⚙'),
            nextcord.SelectOption(label= 'PikaNetwork', description= 'Pika commands', emoji= '<:PikaYay:831858710162047007>'),
            nextcord.SelectOption(label= 'Moderation', description= 'Moderation commands', emoji= '<:developer:940842823165567016>')
        ]
        super().__init__(placeholder= 'Choose something...', min_values= 1, max_values=1, options=options)

    async def callback(self, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        x = []
        for command in self.bot.commands:
            if command.cog and command.cog.qualified_name == self.values[0]:
                x.append(command.name)
        e1= nextcord.Embed(
            title= f'test',
            description= f', '.join(x),
            color= nextcord.Colour.blue()
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=e1, ephemeral=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try removing `self` from `for command in self.bot.commands:`.
2. If you register your bot by using `client = nextcord.Client()`, not `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")`, change the `bot` to `client`.